# How to add ads image in header magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can I add images in my header 320x72(heightxwidth) in Magento 2? My header and footer file and showing in app->design->frontend-> or shopping\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\Magento_Theme\layout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Make new theme in Magento 2 follow below directory

app / design / frontend /  /  / Magento_Theme / templates / html

Step 2. Copy header.phtml files from vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html and paste in app / design / frontend /  /  / Magento_Theme / templates / html

Step 3. Now you can change header.phtml files.

```
    Image can add in header by below code.

<?php 
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  

        $storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 

        $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();

        $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); 
    ?>

    <img scr="<?php echo $mediaUrl.'/image.jpg' ?>">
```